# NullPointerException in integer array

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am having a problem with a null pointer exception.  Please specify some general cases of it.

Here is my code:

```
public class GuessActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener
{
EditText GNum;
Button nxt;
int[] a = new int[4];
int[] d = new int[4];
int t = 0;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> output = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> out = new HashMap<String, String>();
String KEY_NUM , KEY_BULLS , KEY_COWS;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.guess_activity);

    GNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGuessNum);
    nxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btNxt);
    a = getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("num");

    nxt.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btNxt)
    {
        String gN = GNum.getText().toString();
        int l = gN.length();
        int b =0;
        int c =0;
        if(l!=4)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Number should be of 4 digits",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            t++;
            int x = Integer.parseInt(gN);

            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                d[i] = x%10;
                x = x/10;
            }
            if(t>8)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Lost the Game",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            {

                if(d[0] == a[0])
                    b++;
                if(d[0] == a[1] || d[0] == a[2] || d[0] == a[3])
                    c++;
                if(d[1] == a[1])
                    b++;
                if(d[1] == a[0] || d[1] == a[2] || d[1] == a[3])
                    c++;
                if(d[2] == a[2])
                    b++;
                if(d[2] == a[1] || d[2] == a[0] || d[2] == a[3])
                    c++;
                if(d[3] == a[3])
                    b++;
                if(d[3] == a[1] || d[3] == a[2] || d[3] == a[0])
                    c++;

                if(b == 4)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Win",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            out.put(KEY_NUM , gN);
            out.put(KEY_BULLS ,String.valueOf(b));
            out.put(KEY_COWS , String.valueOf(c));

            output.add(out);


            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, output,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { KEY_NUM , KEY_BULLS , KEY_COWS}, new int[] {
                            R.id.tvGuessNum , R.id.tvBulls ,R.id.tvCows });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
            ListView lv = getListView();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
03-04 06:32:58.960: W/dalvikvm(844): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ab2ba8)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844): Process: com.example.game, PID: 844
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.example.game.GuessActivity.onClick(GuessActivity.java:66)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-04 06:32:58.970: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 66 is in the `onClick` method: `d[i] = x % 10`

Comment: Have you checked which value is `null` at the line of your where your exception is thrown?

Comment: "Reply asap" -> no good.

Comment: `general cases`.  A null pointer exception happens when you try to use ("dereference") an object variable which has had no object assigned to  it (it is "uninitialised").  All objects variables in Java are set to null until you do initialise them.  `Object myObject; myObject.toString();` gives NullPointerException.  `Object myObject = new Object();myObject.toString();` works fine.  BTW, learn to use the debugger, then finding these is really easy.

Comment: what is value of `x`?

Comment: Also, don't be lazy.  Use proper names, with proper naming conventions, for your code.  You will not be able to debug your own code in 6 months because it is so hard to read.

Comment: @User2796705 are you sure this is the correct line throwing the Exception?

Comment: @user2796705 I tend to split my code in to smaller methods. When you have small methods that perform a single operation it makes the stack trace easier to debug

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `EditText` (R.id.etGuessNum) doesn't have a value in it.

You should sanitize your input to avoid null references. I would also advise you check to see the value that they have entered is a valid number.

I would also have a quick read through [naming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) [conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) for Java.

Comment: wouldn't this throw a `NumberFormatException` instead of a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Also, he checks for the length of the `EditText`. It would print a toast.

Comment: @Manu - if the length isn't 4, it would step in to the else block.

Comment: @RossDrew You're right. It must have been on another line.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your 3 Strings `KEY_NUM, KEY_BULLS, KEY_COWS` are null.
2. Also, are you sure `a` is not null? `a = getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("num");` might return null.
3. Change

   ```
   if(l!=4)
   {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Number should be of 4 digits",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   if(l!=4)
   {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Number should be of 4 digits",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
       return;
   }
   ```

Comment: the NPE is before that.

Comment: Isn't the problem on line `d[i] = x%10;`

Comment: It can't be, because d, i and x are ints (or arrays of int), which don't throw a NPE

Comment: That's what he says in the description.

Answer (score -1):

change this:

> String gN = GNum.getText().toString(); //can be null

to:

```
String gN = GNum.getText().toString(); //can be null
if(gN == null) 
return;
```

int l = gN.length(); //if edit text is empty this will be null

Comment: getText never returns null. Check the documentation

Comment: and `Integer.parseInt(null)` would throw a different exception to the one shown in this case